# Automatically inserting an \hline every nᵗʰ row of a table

Tags: tables

Is it possible to insert an `\hline` every nth row in a table?

We have several tables that are programmatically generated and have different requirements for `\hline` separation of rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pgfplotstable` has a key the name of which is `every nth row` and which seems to do precisely what you are asking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    every nth row={3[+1]}{before row=\midrule},
]{
a b
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
1 0
1 0
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This example is taken from the manual. Since you are saying you generate the tables automatically, `pgfplotstable` may be particularly attractive.

Comment: This seems to be the deal! thanks!